# How can I tell which command / operation Origen is currently running?

Tags: origen-sdk

In my application code I have logic which could be hit in either a program or a pattern generation run and I need to handle them differently.

How can I tell whether Origen is currently generating a pattern or a program, or any other command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Origen.current_command` will return the name of the currently executing command.

This will return the full name of the command in string format, i.e. if you run `origen g my_pattern` then it will return `"generate"`.

The full names of the most commonly used Origen commands are:

- generate
- program
- interactive
- compile